# How to define space of blank lines in html

Tags: html

I want to know do i define or adjust the blank line spaces created while using the pre tag in html

All the codes and screenshot is attached for better understanding

Hopefully someone will know a fix for it
Thank you in advance

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Blank line's Space Adjustment</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>Sed ac quam varius, ullamcorper massa in, pharetra<br>augue.Etiam quis ultrices nulla.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<br>Sed ac quam varius, ullamcorper massa in, pharetra<br>augue.Etiam quis ultrices nulla.
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand&display=swap');

pre {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 3.90vw;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
```

[Image Showing what i exactly want](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10_sZTXFbxbBO8cwpMGthyfFCuOqQ2AOO/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a sample HTML code with the `<pre>` tag you are using and add two screenshots. One screenshot how the text should be rendered (based on the HTML code you provided) and one screenshot how it should **not** be rendered (where the space between the lines is too big).

Comment: @Progman that would be lot better.  Thanks for suggesting it.  I will update the question with screenshot and actual raw code

Comment: @Progman i have edited the post.  You may now check

Comment: Why do you use the `<pre>` tag, specially when the font is not a monospace font? And why do you not use two separate tags like `<p>` where you can change the margin/padding for the second `<p>`?

Comment: @Progman i am using pre tag mainly because i was tired using the nbsp tag so many times  I have a long text to write.  So i thought pre would be better as i can just copy paste all text directly as it is

Comment: Why do you not use two `<pre>` tags where you can change the margins/paddings as required?

Comment: image do not longer exists, please repair it

Answer (score 2):

HTML is space insensitive i.e it will ignore the 10–20 spaces you made and would consider only 2.

As far as I have seen, the multiple tags used for spacing in HTML are:-

1.) `<br/>`- this one is for the line breaks i.e. to jump onto the next line.

2.) `&nbsp;` - it’s a non-breaking space and you can use it in multiples like     and so on.

3.) `&emsp;` - it’s also non-breaking space but provide space equal to four normal spaces.

3.) `<pre></pre>` - this could be used when you want to display your content as it is typed. You could use this to display code examples, poetry, or any other text in which exact spacing and line breaks are important.

4.) p.indent{ padding-left: 1.8em } - in style tag in head it will add blank space "padding" to the left of the paragraphs. And in body, `<p class=”indent”>`your content`</p>.`

However, the main downside to formatted text using `<pre>` is the width. Unlike normal HTML, it will not resize to match the user's window size but will create a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: Talking of 3rd Point.  The pre tag which i am using to display the text exactly as it is typed.  But i want to change one aspect of it.   Space created due to blank lines

Comment: That shouldn't be impossible just because the pre tag displays text exactly as typed.   pre {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 3.90vw;
  font-family: 'Quicksand',sans serif:}.    I changes these things for pre tag.    There must be something for blank lines.   I hope ur Getting my point

Comment: I have updated the question for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

this is how it is done

```html
 <pre>This is line 1 </br></br>This is line 2</pre>
 

 
<pre>This is line 1


 &nbsp;&nbsp;This is line 2</pre>
```

Comment: This will leave a blank line between line 1 and 2 but i wanted to know how do i adjust the space created by that blank line

Comment: Also i don't see reason of using br tag while already using pre.  Since we are using pre tag , we will insert a blank line normally in plain text , won't we ?

Comment: </br> creates new line but not space if you want space you can use nbsp look at second section

Comment: i have edited the question a lot for better understanding.  Please check

Answer (score 0):

I think, one way you can adjust the space between two line spaces is using a `<br` element with its `line-height` property.

```css
.line-break {
  line-height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<pre>
This is line 1 
<br class="line-break">
This is line 2 
</pre>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying , although i have edited the question for better understanding.   Please check

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like a paragraph spacing property, however I don't think there is one.
There are many different ways to do this without using `<pre>`, however, if you insist on doing so, one way to do this is to remove entirely your blank row, then use `line-height` and then use `margin` to hide the space before and after your rows.
Your wanted white space in between the lines would be almost equal to the `line-height` minus the `font-size`/2

```css
.text-after-pre {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
pre {
  margin-top: -25px;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<pre>
This is line 1 
This is line 2 
</pre>
<div class="text-after-pre">Some more text</div>
```